# How to find the download size of a file on HTTP header called Content-Length?

Tags: php, html, http, header

The question also asks us to find the total download size of a URL. But what if that URL passed into the script just points to a single file resource like a JPG file or a GIF file? Well, for a single file resource we just need to find the size of that particular file and then return it as the answer, and we are done. But, for an HTML document we will need to find the total size of all resources that are embedded and included on the page and return that as the answer

```
function get_remote_file_size($url) {

    $headers = get_headers($url, 1);

    if (isset($headers['Content-Length'])) 

        //checks for lower case "L" in Content-length:
    if (isset($headers['Content-length'])) 
           return $headers['Content-length'];    

}
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The get_headers function accepts a URL as an argument. So, the PHP code to retrieve the “`Content-Length`” header would look like this

```
function get_remote_file_size($url) {

$headers = get_headers($url, 1);

if (isset($headers['Content-Length'])) 
       return $headers['Content-Length'];

    //checks for lower case "L" in Content-length:
if (isset($headers['Content-length'])) 
       return $headers['Content-length'];


}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hitesh for give solutions

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.  You've literally copied and pasted the code from the question.

Comment: in code some error found to i have solve this. `return $headers['Content-Length'];`

Comment: yes it's helpfully for me

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a really complicated question, and one that has no definitive answer.  There's a lot you're going to have to look up, so I'll walk you through the steps.

1. Download the original page HTML.
2. Use a DOM parser to actually parse the HTML into a graph of elements.
3. Iterate through each element, and download any external resources you care about.  This would be the `src` attribute for `<img>`, `<video>`, `<script>`, `<iframe>`, etc.  Don't forget CSS which can be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="..." />`.

This won't be everything though.  You now have a new problem.  What if the JavaScript loads more scripts?  Maybe it adds data via AJAX?  Perhaps the CSS references some graphics or other CSS?  Maybe embedded fonts?

Worse yet, sometimes these things are timed.  Sometimes a script won't load something until there is user interaction, or after a few seconds of being loaded.

On top of that, don't forget that every new item loaded can then bring in its own stuff.  (Ads for example often load several megs of stuff.)

The best thing you can do is use a headless browser like PhantomJS, load the page and let the scripts run, and track all the resources that were downloaded.  Then, wait a few seconds (or until page load is fired if you wish), and add it up.  But, there's no fool-proof definitive time to say when the page is done.